# How to use Strobe Media Playback with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, strobe-media-playback

I am trying to use the Strobe Media Playback plugin to play a video on my website. I am also using codeigniter framework for my site. The video that I am wanting to play is located in root>assets>videos>promo.mov. Below is what the object block looks like:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" width="100%" height="360"> 
    <param name="movie" value="assets/player/Debug%20build%20for%20Flash%20Player%2010.1/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf"></param> 
    <param name="FlashVars" value="??????????"></param> 
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param> 
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param> 
    <embed src="/assets/player/Debug%20build%20for%20Flash%20Player%2010.1/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="100%" height="360" FlashVars="src=??????"></embed> 
</object>
```

The problem is the FlashVars value in the embed tag requires a fully qualified url. However, since I'm using codeigniter I can't simply access the video with http://www.example.com/assets/videos/promo.mov because of the URI routing.

What would the qualified url I can use to access my video?

Comment: you want to show video on your page?? clear out your question

Comment: Yes. I have a link that opens a modal with the video. The user can then play the video.

Comment: this video code is working??

Comment: Yes all is well until I push play and it tells me that it is unable to connect to the content.

Comment: you can use youtube. if you upload video it takes your site  much more heavy and cause to traffic. use youtube

Comment: I've thought about that but I really don't like the look of the player on the site.

Comment: so use html 5 video player

Comment: I will check into that. Out of all the years I've done web design I've never put a video on my site. So this is new for me :)

Comment: what is your video format??

Comment: Originally mov but I have a wmv version and flv version

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: Awesome. That looks like it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use HTML 5 Video player

```
<video controls>
  <source src="somevideo.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="somevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video in WebM with VP8 or MP4 with H.264.
  <!-- You can embed a Flash player here, to play your mp4 video in older browsers -->
</video>
```

**Supported Desktop Browsers**

1. Safari 3.1+
2. Chrome 3.0+
3. Internet Explorer 9.0+
4. Firefox 21, 24 (disabled by default in 24, depends on system codec)

**Supported Mobile Browsers**

1. Android Browser 3.0+
2. Safari (iOS) 3.1+
3. Firefox (Android) 17.0+
4. Internet Explorer (Windows Phone) 9.0+

**Just get it working**

1. HTML5, Flash, Mobile: MP4/H.264, Baseline profile, 640×480
2. HTML5: WebM
3. Round it out a little
4. HTML5, Flash: MP4/H.264, High profile
5. HTML5: WebM
6. Mobile: MP4/H.264, Baseline profile, 480×360 or 640×480

**Support everything well**

1. HTML5, Flash: MP4/H.264, High profile
2. HTML5: WebM
3. HTML5: Ogg
4. Mobile: MP4/H.264, Baseline profile, 480×360, for older mobile devices
5. Mobile: MP4/H.264, Main profile, 1280×720, for older iOS devices (iPhone 4 and older iPads/Apple TV). The newest devices (iPhone 5, etc) can support the desktop High profile rendition.
6. Mobile: 3GP/MPEG4, 320×240 and/or 177×144, for non-smartphones*

**You can get more idea  on**

1. [blog.zencoder.com](http://blog.zencoder.com/2013/09/13/what-formats-do-i-need-for-html5-video/)
2. [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats)